# Slick 3.0 Read rows in batches of 1000

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I am using slick 3.0 Streaming API against MySQL database. Can I read 1000 rows at a time (the table is very large). till the entire table has been read?

it will be kind if you could point me to a sample which does that.

I can see the streaming API documentation, but I guess that reads 1 row at a time.

I want to read 1000 rows at a time, write them somewhere and then read another 1000 till the entire table is done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for paging. In slick you do this by dropping and taking.

```
query.drop(offset).take(pageSize)
```

This will add the limit and offset values to your query.

Here is the documentation which has some examples: http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/queries.html#sorting-and-filtering